# Resharper Trap "Convert to 'return' statement"

Tags: c#, resharper, ternary-operator

Given the following routine:

```
private static object ParseNumber(string token, FieldDefinition def)
{
  if (def.Fraction > 0)
    return Double.Parse(token);
  else
    return Int64.Parse(token);
}
```

Resharper offers me the option to refactor it into a statement with the ternary operator:

```
private static object ParseNumber(string token, FieldDefinition def)
{
  return def.Fraction > 0 ? Double.Parse(token) : Int64.Parse(token);
}
```

Who can spot the trap?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Okay, change to previous answer. Because there's an implicit conversion from `Int64` to `Double` (but not vice versa), that will be the result type of the expression. So when you expect to get a boxed `Int64`, you actually get a boxed `Double` (but with a value which originally came from `Int64.Parse`).

Just in case that's not clear enough, let's change all the `return` statements such that they just return a variable. Here's the original code:

```
private static object ParseNumber(string token, FieldDefinition def)
{
  if (def.Fraction > 0)
    return Double.Parse(token);
  else
    return Int64.Parse(token);
}
```

Convert that appropriately:

```
private static object ParseNumber(string token, FieldDefinition def)
{
  if (def.Fraction > 0)
  {
    double d = Double.Parse(token);
    object boxed = d; // Result is a boxed Double
    return boxed;
  }
  else
  {
    long l = Int64.Parse(token);
    object boxed = l; // Result is a boxed Int64
    return boxed;
  }
}
```

And now let's do the same to the version with the conditional operator:

```
private static object ParseNumber(string token, FieldDefinition def)
{
  return def.Fraction > 0 ? Double.Parse(token) : Int64.Parse(token);
}
```

becomes

```
private static object ParseNumber(string token, FieldDefinition def)
{
  // The Int64.Parse branch will implicitly convert to Double
  double d = def.Fraction > 0 ? Double.Parse(token) : Int64.Parse(token);
  object boxed = d; // *Always* a Double
  return boxed;
}
```

EDIT: As requested, a bit more information. The type of a conditional expression of the form

```
X ? Y : Z
```

depends on the types of `Y` and `Z`, which I'll call `TY` and `TZ`. There are a few options:

- `TY` and `TZ` are the same type: result is that type
- There's an implicit conversion from `TY` to `TZ` but not from `TZ` to `TY`: the result is of type `TZ` and the conversion is used if the first branch is used.
- There's an implicit conversion from `TZ` to `TY` but not from `TY` to `TZ`: the result is of type `TY` and the conversion is used if the second branch is used.
- There's an implicit conversion in both directions: compile-time error
- There are no conversions either way: compile-time error

Does that help?

Comment: I posted it about 6 months back on CodeProject. In fact, it is scary that an integer is implicitly a double, even though it loose precision.

Comment: Could you maybe add a sentence or two about why the implicit conversion to double occurs? (presumably some property of the ternary/conditional operator)